# UITableViewCell with embedded vertical Stack View setup with auto layout and dynamic height

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder, uistackview

I am trying to make a dynamic cell using stack view embedded in a cell so when items are added to the cell the height of cell adapt to the height of the stack view but not getting the expected results meaning I get ambitious constraints.
Here is how to set the setup is.I have a cell with an embedded stack view:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

override var reuseIdentifier: String? {
    return "cell"
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

    @IBOutlet public weak var stack: UIStackView?

}
```

This is how the nib looks like:

[image]

in table view code I have the following:

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

public  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCell

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {

        for _ in 0...10 {
            let view = MyView()
            cell.stack!.addArrangedSubview(view)
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

where MyView is:

```
class MyView: UIView {

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

    setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)


    backgroundColor = .blue
    return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems the mistake was coming from anchoring the bottom of stack view to the bottom of the content view, instead one should anchor the bottom of the last view on the stack to the bottom of the contentView.